# How do I integrate my Submit function in Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to integrate my submit function that sends the data gotten from the form to my django API.
I have done the form validation with formik and I have tried calling the function to post the data.

How my onSubmit function for formik looks:

```
const Registration = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      re_password: "",
    }}
    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      handleRegistration(values, this.props.history);
      setSubmitting(false);
    }}
  >
```

And the function for submitting data to the server:

```
const handleRegistration = (e, values) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(values),
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("registration res", res);
      window.location.href = "/login";
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("registration error", error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you see any message printed? Please include your response to the http request. Or error if your onSubmit function is not working.

Comment: No error message is printed. Is there a better way of adding the function to Formik onSubmit?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'm submitting with formik:

```
const onSubmit = (values, { resetForm, setSubmitting }) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    setSubmitting(true);
    data.append('form', JSON.stringify({ values.firstValue, values.secondValue }));
    // call post('/yourEndpoint', data)
};
```

Any particular reason you're using `setSubmitting(false)` ? I also see you have `e.preventDefault();` and I'm not sure if you need that.